# Is it possible to get the UI culture of a SignalR client to send localized content?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

It's easy enough for me to send messages via SignalR to specific users:

```
await _hubContext.Clients.User(userIDString).SendAsync("remoteMethod", data);
```

The challenge is that I can't figure out how to send that message string accounting for the user's culture (en, fr, nl, es, etc). With a straight up hit to a regular endpoint, you just use `Resources.PropertyName` and it magically works based on the user's browser culture. But if I want to tailor the `data` above to the user's culture, I don't know how. In fact, if this code fires as a result of a different user, the current UI culture is of *that* user.

Comment: Your codes seems send message outside the hub? I think you could try to get user's language from Accept-Language in the requestheader,accroding to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-accept-language-http-header-1

Comment: There is no context like that from the connected user at that point. If there's an httpcontext at all, it's from the user making the request.

Comment: There would also be a httpcontext  for httpconnection, you could get the httpcontext with GetHttpContext() method  in hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it makes sense that what I'm asking isn't easily possible. Each registered client has little more than an ID to work with. While you could do some magic with an implementation of `IUserIdProvider` to map userID's to culture, you would then have to maintain extra state to do so, and I didn't want to be in that business.

My solution was to simply serialize a bunch of resource strings and have the client call them from a controller action. I have the client cache it with `[ResponseCache(Duration = 600, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]`, and the resulting Javascript object is a global variable available to all the things on the client.

Answer (score 1):

For httpconnections,you could also get httpcontext with  GetHttpcontext() method
And here's the document related:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-context-object

I tried as below in hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public string Culture()
        {
            var culture = this.Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
            return (culture);
        }
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
            => await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, this.Culture());
    }
```

The test result:
[image]

Comment: That's the culture from the context of the user calling the hub. It will send the same culture to all of the clients. That's not what I was after.